# Whose heaven is it anyway?

Tags: supernatural

In *Supernatural*, everyone who goes to heaven makes their own little heaven.

Raphael borrows one of these in The Man Who Would Be King, and Castiel doubts the heaven-makers admittance. Do we know who that is?

Comment: Wow, I listened twice and I didn't hear 'Ken Lay'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The dialog in question has multiple meanings even though it appears to be some throw-away dialog between the two characters of Castiel and Archangel Raphael.

> Castiel:   Whose heaven is this?
>   Raphael:  Ken Lay's.  I'm borrowing it.
>   Castiel:  I still question his admittance here.
>   Raphael:  He's devout.  Trumps everything.

[Kenneth Lay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenneth_Lay) was a businessman who was involved in the corruption scandal that ultimately destroyed the Enron Corporation. Lay was the CEO and chairman of Enron during the time of most of the counts against Enron were levied. Lay died of a heart attack presumably cause by coronary heart disease. His body was cremated and no autopsy was performed. Numerous conspiracy theories surround his death.

> Kenneth Lee "Ken" Lay (April 15, 1942 – July 5, 2006) was an American businessman, best known for his role in the widely reported corruption scandal that led to the downfall of Enron Corporation. Lay and Enron became synonymous with corporate abuse and accounting fraud when the scandal broke in 2001. Lay was the CEO and chairman of Enron from 1985 until his resignation on January 23, 2002, except for a few months in 2000 when he was chairman and Jeffrey Skilling was chief executive officer (CEO). He took a regional natural gas pipeline business and turned it into a energy conglomerate with a market capitalization of $70 billion, betting the future on unregulated energy markets.

The hidden joke/message is Raphael is using the Heaven of a corrupt man during what would appear to be a corrupt attempt at a takeover of the leadership of all of Heaven. Castiel casts doubts on Lay's entry to Heaven based on his life's work. Raphael (who appears to have been responsible for Lay's entry) said that Lay was devout and that is all that mattered. So Lay may have entered Heaven on a technicality, adjudicated by Raphael for the purpose of using that personal Heaven as a base of operations.

Answer (score 2):

The garden Castiel is in at the beginning of the episode:

> Castiel:  After supposedly saving Sam, I finally returned to heaven.  Of course, there isn't one heaven, each soul generates its own paradise.  I favor the the eternal Tuesday afternoon of an autistic man who drowned in a bathtub in 1953.

The office Raphael invites Castiel to:

> Castiel:   Who's heaven is this?
>   Raphael:  Ken Lay's.  I'm borrowing it.
>   Castiel:  I still question his admittance here.
>   Raphael:  He's devout.  Trumps everything.

Castiel doesn't like him and the name isn't familiar to me.  I don't think Ken Lay made any appearance at any point in the series.